# C++ - Why do [pointer] and this->[pointer] give different values?

Tags: c++, pointers, allegro, allegro5

I have a `GameWorld` class, in which I have `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;`

I'm trying to define an object that has a pointer to the `GameWorld` object, which it then uses to access `display`. In my struggles to get that to reference properly, I noticed that my pointers are giving me results that none of the tutorials/explanations/prior knowledge I have can explain.

[A screenshot of some testing I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi16l.png)

Now, in my my mind, lines 1 and 3 should cout the same value. It's my understanding that line 1 is outputting the address of `display`, and line 2 is outputting the address of the `GameWorld`. Shouldn't line 3 output the address of the `display` pointed to by the `GameWorld`?

In short, how can I access the same value outputted by line 1 through a reference to the `GameWorld`?`

`GameWorld.cpp:`

```
#include "GameWorld.h"
#include "Assets.h"
#include "Tile.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

GameWorld::GameWorld() {}

GameWorld::~GameWorld()
{
    if (display) { al_destroy_display(display); }
    if (timer) { al_destroy_timer(timer); }
    if (queue) { al_destroy_event_queue(queue); }
}

void GameWorld::Incept()
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *queue = NULL;

    if (!al_init()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize Allegro!\n");
    return;
}

if (!al_init_image_addon()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize image addons!\n");
    return;
}

if (!al_install_keyboard()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize keyboard!\n");
    return;
}

if (!al_install_mouse()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize mouse!\n");
    return;
}

display = al_create_display(800, 640);
if (!display) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
    return;
}
al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
al_flip_display(); 

timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / 60);
if (!timer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create timer!\n");
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return;
}

queue = al_create_event_queue();
if (!queue) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create event queue!\n");
    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    return;
}

al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());

Tilesheet = al_load_bitmap("Bin/Tilesheet.bmp");

fprintf(stderr, "Running smooth!\n");

/*
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5> Bjergen = Assets::L2;

for (std::size_t i3 = 0; i3 < Bjergen.size(); i3++){
    for (std::size_t j3 = 0; j3 < Bjergen[i3].size(); j3++){
        std::cout << Bjergen[i3][j3] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
*/

Tile T1(*this, display, 0, 0, 0);
//Tile T2(this, display, 1, 16, 0);
//Tile T3(this, display, 32, 32, 0);
std::cout << display << " actual display" << std::endl;
std::cout << this << " gameworld" << std::endl;
std::cout << this->display << std::endl;
std::cout << &(this->display) << std::endl;
std::cout << (this->display) << std::endl;
std::cout << &this->display << std::endl;

al_start_timer(timer);
bool draw = true;
bool PlayingGame = true;

while (PlayingGame){
    ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
    al_wait_for_event(queue, &ev);
    // START EVENT LISTENING
    if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER){
        draw = true;
    }
    else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE){
        PlayingGame = false;
    }
    else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN){
        if (ev.keyboard.keycode == ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN){}
    }
    else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP){}
    else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN){
        std::cout << " (" << ev.mouse.x << "," << ev.mouse.y << ")\n";
    }
    // END EVENT LISTENING
    if (draw && al_is_event_queue_empty(queue)){
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
        T1.Draw();
        //T2.Draw();
        //T3.Draw();
        al_flip_display();
    }
}
//GAME IS ENDING
al_destroy_display(display);
al_destroy_timer(timer);
al_destroy_event_queue(queue);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, not a link to a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: My guess is you've hidden the variable, but without code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: `this->display` may refer to a different `display` than `display`

Comment: Exactly what @clcto, said: `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;`

Comment: @AndreyT, If I'm reading correctly, it's just the first `if` ending too far left.

Comment: The square brackets in your title are confusing.

Comment: I apologize. It is my understanding that the convention of using square brackets is that something like [object] implies an object with an arbitrary name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a local variable called `display` within `GameWorld::Incept()` that is hiding the `display` member variable of the `GameWorld` class.

Comment: Well golly gee, that's embarrassing. That's what I get for following bad tutorials.

Comment: @GregKritzman: :-)  We've all been there.  You might want to use a naming convention, eg. naming your member variables like `m_display`.

Comment: While I might start doing that, I don't think that would've helped in this situation. IIRC, the tutorial I originally followed did everything in `main`, and I was adapting it to be done by an object. My problem was that I didn't fully think through how variables might be handled differently. Even with the different convention, it's likely I would've just had two `m_display`s floating around.

Comment: @GregKritzman The naming convention RicheHindle mentions is also useful because you cannot have a member and member function of the same name.